# Specifying array element within EVAL function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eval

I am attempting to create a number of parameter arrays using the `eval` function in MATLAB

Essentially, I have a big dataset (`data`) which I am attempting to split into a number of smaller datasets, with names which are generated using a loop.  As it stands, I am using:

```
variablename = ['a' num2str(academy) '_s' num2str(year) '_g' num2str(gender)];

        %loop through all people, if match various classifications, write to variablename
        for row = 1:totalrows;
            if data(row,2) == academy;
                if data(row,1) == year;
                    if data(row,70) == gender;
                         eval([variablename ' = [ data(row,8) data(row,9) data(row,73) data(row,76) data(row,77) data(row,78) data(row,79) ]; ' ]); % ; supresses output (i.e. stop it showing value of each variable                     


                    end%gender if
                end%year if
            end %academy if
        end %row loop
```

This works reasonably well, except that each time I get a second record matching all `if` statements, it overwrites the first set of data.

So my question is, how can I specify the row of the variable created using `eval` to which i want to write my data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: all database tables have an index key separate from everything else that ensures you don't run into such a problem. Perhaps you can include row as an immediate parameter in your eval script

Comment: Thanks for this, prompted me to look again into the details and worked out the required notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompted by the replies, I checked through the formatting and the following worked

```
 eval([variablename '(row,:) = [ data(row,8) data(row,9) data(row,73) data(row,76) data(row,77) data(row,78) data(row,79) ]; ' ]); % ; supresses output (i.e. stop it showing value of each variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using EVAL, consider this:

```
data = [...];           %# some big matrix, rows are records, columns are fields

year = 2012;
gender = 2;             %# female
academy = 5;            %# corresponds to some meaningful value

cols = [8 9 73 76:79];  %# list of columns to select

%# get all rows matching the above conditions
idx = ( data(:,1)==year && data(:,70)==gender && data(:,2)==academy );
X = data(idx,cols);
```

If you are doing multiple queries of this type, maybe you could store the result in a cell array, and keep a separate matrix to store the query params, something like:

```
map(1,:) = [2012 2 5];  %# for the above query, with X{1} containing the data
map(2,:) = [2003 1 4];  %# for another query, with X{2} for corresponding data
```

Comment: Thanks for this, found a very minor alteration to the original code which made it work, but this may be very useful in the future.  Thanks!